# Docker Remote API to login to registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am looking for documentation for docker login, I need to login to a registry to pull docker image and I need to do it remotely using docker remote APIs.

But unfortunately I am unable to find docker remote API docs, any help would be greatly appreciated.

API doc :
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.19/

Thanks in advance.
Sarath Krishnan

Answer (score 1):

you go as

```
 docker login your.domain.to.the.registr.without.protocol.or.port
 enter username
 enter password
```

now you can pull using `docker pull your.domain.to.the.registr.without.protocol.or.port/youimage`

Ensure your registry runs behind a SSL proxy / termination, or you run into security issues. Consider reading this in this case https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am able to do it from Docker host, I am trying to use Docker Remote API to do it.  I am using the API : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.20/#/push-an-image-on-the-registry . On the Header I am setting X-Registry-Auth and its value - {'username': 'user', 'password': 'paasswd', 'email': 'sarath@company.com', 'serveraddress' : 'server.com'} . When I do it I am getting 401 Authentication failed . But when I use the same credentials I am able to login from docker host using cli.

Comment: @Sarathkrish Did you resolved this issue?